# Scheduling for 8 teams playing 7 games where teams can play other teams only once and teams can't repeat games

Tags: combinatorics

I am setting up a game for Easter camp where there will be 8 teams and 7 DIFFERENT games. The rule are:

1. Each team must play with the other 7 teams at least once.
2. Each team must go through and play all 7 games only once.

Ideally there would be 7 rounds.

Any help would be much appreciated as my 1 int brain can't think of any solution at all.
Cheers.

Update:
Another rule has been given where teams can only play once each round meaning in each round 3 games will be on standby as there are only 4 pairs that can play.

Comment: What have you tried? People will be more willing to answer your question if they can see you have put in some effort yourself first. It will also allow us to see what your current level of knowledge is so we don't confuse you more

Comment: See [round-robin tournament scheduling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm).

Comment: I have tried the round robin way of coming up with the pairs but every time I move on to making the table where the games are the headers and I always find some pairs where one team is repeated under the same game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very relevant to this question is a $7$-edge-coloring of the complete graph $K_8$ on $8$ vertices. See the second image on [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring) for an example of such a coloring. Such a coloring can be interpreted in two ways:

First, each color corresponds to a round, with an edge of that color representing the pairs of teams that play a match. This gives you a tournament of precisely $7$ rounds in which every pair of teams plays a match. It doesn't tell you which game is played in a match, however.

Second, each color corresponds to a game, with an edge of that color representing a pair of teams playing that game in a mach. It doesn't tell you in which round the match takes place, however.

So the ideal solution would be to combine these two interpretations of a $7$-coloring of $K_8$. To do so, it suffices to find two different $7$-colorings of $K_8$ with the property that any pair of colors has at most $1$ edge in common across the two different colorings.

Comment: thank you very much. I think I have a general idea now of what I need to do.
Appreciate the help.

Comment: @John I have added some more details on how to use these colorings of $K_8$ to construct such a tournament, if it exists.

Comment: so ideally the solution would be taken from over lapping 2 instances of the coloring where 1 coloring represents the rounds while the other represents the games?

Comment: Exactly. And with this overlapping each edge gets two colors $(x,y)$. To get a tournament, no two edges can have the same pair of colors $(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks, this helped quite a lot